# How to verify sort order of columns on an Infragistics grid using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sorting, selenium, infragistics

I need to verify the sort order of the below HTML table columns. In the full HTML page, the column headers can be clicked on to sort asc and desc. Note that the data in the table is dynamic, so I'm not going to always know what will be inside of there and cant simply store hard coded values before the test begins.

I am a beginner with C# and Selenium, so I don't know how to verify sort order of an HTML table. My test contains everything up until the verification of the sort. I already have code in place to navigate to the page/table, and also have code in place click on one of the column headers. But then I dont know where to begin on how to verify that the column I clicked on did indeed sort ascending after the click.

I know that I probably have to store 2 string array variables. 1 array as the list, as is, after the click. Then 1 array where I take the list and sort it using a C# class of some sort. Then do a compare. But I am just learning C#, so can someone help me out on how to accomplish this using Selenium and C#.

I found something that is similar to what I need to accomplish (http://grokbase.com/t/gg/selenium-users/125g89zssv/selenium-webdriver-how-to-verify-whether-list-containing-rows-from-a-table-is-sorted), however I think that is coded in Java.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1250">
  <meta name="generator" content="PSPad editor, www.pspad.com">
  <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" data-bind="igGrid: gridOptions" id="ap-orgconfig-orgs" aria-multiselectable="false" role="grid" class="ui-iggrid-table ui-widget-content" aria-describedby="ap-orgconfig-orgs_container" style="table-layout: fixed; overflow: hidden;">
  <colgroup>
  <col style="width: 50%;">
  <col style="width: 25%;">
  <col style="width: 25%;">
  </colgroup>
  <thead role="rowgroup">
    <tr role="row" data-header-row="">
      <th id="ap-orgconfig-orgs_Name" role="columnheader" aria-label="Name" tabindex="0" class="ui-iggrid-header ui-widget-header ui-iggrid-sortableheader ui-state-default" title="Sort column">
        <div data-resizinghandle="true" style="position: relative; width: 100%; height: 0px; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
          <a title="">
            <span data-nonpaddedindicator="right" title="" style="position: absolute; margin-right: -6px; right: 0px; width: 5px;" class="ui-iggrid-resizing-handle-cursor ui-iggrid-resizing-handle">
            </span></a>
        </div>
        <span class="ui-iggrid-headertext">Name
        </span>
        <span class="ui-iggrid-colindicator">
        </span>
      </th>
      <th id="ap-orgconfig-orgs_ShortName" role="columnheader" aria-label="Display Name" tabindex="0" class="ui-iggrid-header ui-widget-header ui-iggrid-sortableheader ui-state-default" title="Sort column">
        <div data-resizinghandle="true" style="position: relative; width: 100%; height: 0px; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
          <a title="">
            <span data-nonpaddedindicator="right" title="" style="position: absolute; margin-right: -6px; right: 0px; width: 5px;" class="ui-iggrid-resizing-handle-cursor ui-iggrid-resizing-handle">
            </span></a>
        </div>
        <span class="ui-iggrid-headertext">Display Name
        </span>
        <span class="ui-iggrid-colindicator">
        </span>
      </th>
      <th id="ap-orgconfig-orgs_Type" role="columnheader" aria-label="Type" tabindex="0" class="ui-iggrid-header ui-widget-header ui-iggrid-sortableheader ui-state-default" title="Sort column">
        <div data-resizinghandle="true" style="position: relative; width: 100%; height: 0px; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
          <a title="">
            <span data-nonpaddedindicator="right" title="" style="position: absolute; margin-right: -6px; right: 0px; width: 5px;" class="ui-iggrid-resizing-handle-cursor ui-iggrid-resizing-handle">
            </span></a>
        </div>
        <span class="ui-iggrid-headertext">Type
        </span>
        <span class="ui-iggrid-colindicator">
        </span>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody role="rowgroup" class="ui-widget-content ui-iggrid-tablebody ui-ig-record ui-iggrid-record">
    <tr tabindex="0" role="row" data-id="05f1e963-5a94-47d0-b9c0-3019906d0b25">
      <td tabindex="0" aria-describedby="ap-orgconfig-orgs_Name" aria-readonly="false" role="gridcell" class="">QA Test Organization</td>
      <td tabindex="0" aria-describedby="ap-orgconfig-orgs_ShortName" aria-readonly="false" role="gridcell" class="">QA-ORG</td>
      <td tabindex="0" aria-describedby="ap-orgconfig-orgs_Type" aria-readonly="false" role="gridcell" class="">Consumer</td>
    </tr>
    <tr tabindex="0" role="row" data-id="bb0d84aa-856b-4b89-a380-63bca7a0133f" class="ui-ig-altrecord ui-iggrid-altrecord">
      <td tabindex="0" aria-describedby="ap-orgconfig-orgs_Name" aria-readonly="false" role="gridcell" class="">The CIA Network </td>
      <td tabindex="0" aria-describedby="ap-orgconfig-orgs_ShortName" aria-readonly="false" role="gridcell" class="">CIANyde</td>
      <td tabindex="0" aria-describedby="ap-orgconfig-orgs_Type" aria-readonly="false" role="gridcell" class="">Network</td>
    </tr>
    <tr tabindex="0" role="row" data-id="fb311950-5aa2-4124-b69c-026d47e94e73" class="" aria-selected="true">
      <td tabindex="0" aria-describedby="ap-orgconfig-orgs_Name" aria-readonly="false" role="gridcell" class="ui-iggrid-selectedcell ui-state-active">The Mockingbird Network</td>
      <td tabindex="0" aria-describedby="ap-orgconfig-orgs_ShortName" aria-readonly="false" role="gridcell" class="ui-iggrid-selectedcell ui-state-active">AgitProp</td>
      <td tabindex="0" aria-describedby="ap-orgconfig-orgs_Type" aria-readonly="false" role="gridcell" class="ui-iggrid-selectedcell ui-state-active">Network</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot class="" role="rowgroup" id="ap-orgconfig-orgs_footer_container" style="display: none;">
  </tfoot>
</table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do the cell or row elements in the DOM get resorted when you sort by a column in the UI?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed the approach in the link you provided seems to be working but if the data is sorted does not mean that the column itself is sorted (it could be initially sorted). There are a couple of other checks you need to do in order to verify that the column is sorted. First are the UI parts – the order of the data (to determine the sort direction is ascending or descending), the proper styling of the cells, the proper styling of the header cell, the proper indicator. Second you should check whether the correct expression is added in the data source object. I prepared a simple test case with a test page to demonstrate the things that I'm talking about.
This is the code of the test page - a simple grid with Sorting enabled.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
 <title>Sample</title>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

 <link href="http://cdn-na.infragistics.com/igniteui/2015.2/latest/css/themes/infragistics/infragistics.theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <link href="http://cdn-na.infragistics.com/igniteui/2015.2/latest/css/structure/infragistics.css" rel="stylesheet" />

 <script src="http://modernizr.com/downloads/modernizr-latest.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

 <!-- Ignite UI Required Combined JavaScript Files -->
 <script src="http://cdn-na.infragistics.com/igniteui/2015.2/latest/js/infragistics.core.js"></script>
 <script src="http://cdn-na.infragistics.com/igniteui/2015.2/latest/js/infragistics.lob.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
   var products = new Array(), i = 0;
   for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    products.push({
     "ProductID": i,
     "Number": i,
     "ProductDescription": "Water" + i,
     "UnitPrice": "$ " + i,
     "InStock": i % 2 === 0
    });
   }

   $('#grid1').igGrid({
    virtualization: false,
    autoGenerateColumns: false,
    dataSource: products,
    columns: [
     { headerText: "ProductID", key: "ProductID", width: "200px", dataType: "number" },
     { headerText: "Number", key: "Number", width: "200px", dataType: "number" },
     { headerText: "Description", key: "ProductDescription", width: "200px", dataType: "string" },
     { headerText: "InStock", key: "InStock", width: "200px", dataType: "bool" }
    ],
    features: [
     {
      name: "Sorting"
     }
    ],
    primaryKey: "ProductID"
   });
  });
 </script>
</head>
<body>
 <table id="grid1"></table>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is the code of the test itself.

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using OpenQA.Selenium.IE;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Remote;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using System.Reflection;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;


namespace VerifySorting
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for UnitTest1
    /// </summary>
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        public UnitTest1()
        {
            //
            // TODO: Add constructor logic here
            //
        }

        private TestContext testContextInstance;
        private RemoteWebDriver driver;

        /// <summary>
        ///Gets or sets the test context which provides
        ///information about and functionality for the current test run.
        ///</summary>
        public TestContext TestContext
        {
            get
            {
                return testContextInstance;
            }
            set
            {
                testContextInstance = value;
            }
        }

        #region Additional test attributes
        //
        // You can use the following additional attributes as you write your tests:
        //
        // Use ClassInitialize to run code before running the first test in the class
        // [ClassInitialize()]
        // public static void MyClassInitialize(TestContext testContext) { }
        //
        // Use ClassCleanup to run code after all tests in a class have run
        // [ClassCleanup()]
        // public static void MyClassCleanup() { }
        //
        // Use TestInitialize to run code before running each test 
        // [TestInitialize()]
        // public void MyTestInitialize() { }
        //
        // Use TestCleanup to run code after each test has run
        [TestCleanup()]
        public void MyTestCleanup() {
            this.driver.Quit();
        }

        #endregion

        [TestMethod]
        public void ChromeDriverTest()
        {
            ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
            string name = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
            string dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(name);
            int index = 0;
            bool isAsc = true, isDesc = true;
            string expr;

            #region Driver instantiation and navigation to the test page
            RemoteWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(dir + "\\..\\..\\driver", chromeOptions);
            this.driver = driver;
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(dir + "\\..\\..\\page.htm");
            #endregion // Driver instantiation and navigation to the test page

            #region Finding elements on page and sorting
            IWebElement grid = driver.FindElementById("grid1");

            IWebElement thead = grid.FindElement(By.TagName("thead"));
            ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> ths = thead.FindElements(By.XPath("tr/th"));

            ths[index].Click();

            IWebElement tbody = grid.FindElement(By.TagName("tbody"));
            ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> trs = tbody.FindElements(By.TagName("tr"));

            List<IWebElement> tds = new List<IWebElement>();

            for (int i = 0; i < trs.Count; i++)
            {
                tds.Add(trs[i].FindElement(By.XPath("td[" + (index + 1) + "]")));
            }
            #endregion // Finding elements on page and sorting

            #region Verification of the sort order
            int count = tds.Count;
            for (int i = 1; i < count; i++)
            {
                if (tds[i - 1].Text.CompareTo(tds[i].Text) < 0)
                {
                    isDesc = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

            for (int i = 1; i < count; i++)
            {
                if (tds[i - 1].Text.CompareTo(tds[i].Text) > 0)
                {
                    isAsc = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

            Assert.IsTrue(isAsc || isDesc, "The column is not sorted.");
            #endregion // Verification of the sort order

            #region UI verifications
            expr = driver.ExecuteScript("return $('#grid1').data('igGrid').dataSource.settings.sorting.expressions[0].dir").ToString();
            if (isAsc)
            {
                Assert.IsTrue(expr == "asc");
                Assert.IsTrue(ths[index].GetAttribute("title") == "Sorted ascending");
                Assert.IsTrue(ths[index].GetAttribute("class").Contains("ui-iggrid-colheaderasc"));
                Assert.IsTrue(ths[index].GetAttribute("class").Contains("ui-iggrid-sortableheader"));
                Assert.IsTrue(ths[index].FindElement(By.XPath("div/span")).GetAttribute("class").Contains("ui-iggrid-colindicator-asc"));

                for (int i = 0; i < tds.Count; i++)
                {
                    Assert.IsTrue(tds[i].GetAttribute("class").Contains("ui-iggrid-colasc ui-state-highlight"));
                }
            }
            if (isDesc)
            {
                Assert.IsTrue(expr == "desc");
                Assert.IsTrue(ths[index].GetAttribute("title") == "Sorted descending");
                Assert.IsTrue(ths[index].GetAttribute("class").Contains("ui-iggrid-colheaderdesc"));
                Assert.IsTrue(ths[index].GetAttribute("class").Contains("ui-iggrid-sortableheader"));
                Assert.IsTrue(ths[index].FindElement(By.XPath("div/span")).GetAttribute("class").Contains("ui-iggrid-colindicator-desc"));

                for (int i = 0; i < tds.Count; i++)
                {
                    Assert.IsTrue(tds[i].GetAttribute("class").Contains("ui-iggrid-coldesc ui-state-highlight"));
                }
            }
            #endregion // UI verifications
        }
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that this is just and example. You can modify it as much as you as long as it serves your needs.